# Integration Stata 14 and Sublime Text 3 doesn't run the .do file

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, stata, sublimetext

I installed StataEditor and Pywin32 as suggested at: https://github.com/mattiasnordin/StataEditor. However, when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in Sublime Text Stata is opened but doesn't run the selected lines of code.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions in https://github.com/mattiasnordin/StataEditor/issues/8 or https://github.com/mattiasnordin/StataEditor/issues/13? Most likely it is due to automation not being set up properly. Try following the instructions for Windows Vista (regardless of which version of Windows you're running).

Comment: Thanks, @matnor! Following the guidelines for Windows Vista [http://www.stata.com/automation/#install](http://www.stata.com/automation/#instal) worked perfectly!